# Fallback for get_html_translation_table at PHP Version 5.2.27

Tags: php

I recently changed the default encoding of our project to UTF-8 to guarantee internationality. Now I am fixing some minor problems but there is one I came across which makes me suffer a bit.

The original encoding was ISO-8859-1 and the origin developer used the `get_html_translation_table()` function at different places.

At PHP Version **5.2.17** (*on which the application is running*) there have been only two arguments passed to this function: $table and $quote_style. The problem is, the function assumed ISO-8859-1 as a default and ignores settings like `ini_set('default_charset', 'UTF-8)`

At never PHP Versions, some Arguments were added to the function, one of them is `$encoding`. In addition, **UTF-8** replaced **ISO-8859-1** as a default inside the function.

I want to replace as less code as possible in the project to move from ISO-8859-1 to UTF-8 but I have to fix this because of wrong results.

How can I get the new "*right*" functionality of `get_html_translation_table()` as a fallback version with he same behavior in my project.

Comment: You can always get the list of translations in your local development box (there aren't many) and hard-code it in a custom function. However, whether that solves your needs depends on, well, your needs. `htmlentities()` will obviously *not* use your list but also the function itself has little use with UTF-8. What do you need those HTML entities for?

Comment: You're probably already aware of this, but PHP 5.2 is obsolete. It was declared end of life three years ago, and has had no new security patches since then. There are *known* security issues with it and no fixes will be done for them. If you're still running PHP 5.2 on a production server, then your system administrator (or whoever is calling the shots) is being negligent. You urgently need to upgrade; and note that 5.3 is now also in the end-of-life cycle. The longer you leave this, the harder it will be to upgrade when you finally get around to it. Seriously: upgrade as soon as possible.

Comment: I know that 5.2 is old, I know that i should upgrade ASAP, but I am afraid it does not depend on me. I am literally not allowed to upgrade yet.

Comment: Having no context, function name, comments or sample data I find it almost impossible to know what that function is supposed to do. It looks like a convoluted rewrite of `htmlentities()` —which is basically useless when producing HTML encoded as UTF-8— but it's hard to say.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
/* calls get_html_translation_table with 'ISO-8859-1' as encoding
 * since the third argument is only supported after PHP 5.3.4
 */
function my_get_html_translation_table($str) {
    if (version_compare(PHP_VERSION, '5.3.4') >= 0) {
        return get_html_translation_table(HTML_ENTITIES, ENT_COMPAT, 'ISO-8859-1');
    } else {
        return get_html_translation_table(HTML_ENTITIES, ENT_COMPAT);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, better late then never :)

Answer (score 0):

As i stumbled though the codebase, I came more and more across of the usage of get_html_translation_table(). I now understand what the original intention was with all this. I guess i absolutely wasted my time to find a solution for something which will work 'out-of-the-box' with utf-8 characters pretty well.

I just have to skip original code and use just the normal htmlentities() instead -_-